# Difference between wsdl generaton of synch vs async methods

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asynchronous, wsdl

What is the actual difference in the wsdl for synch methods vs async methods ? Is it possible to write wsdl by hand and then create async service Interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference.  Parsing the wsdl and creating the proxies is the service-orientated equivalent of performing reflection in an object-orientated context.  The definition of the service and how it presents its metadata to the outside world is a purely service-side concept.

The way proxies are generated (synchronous or asynchronous - and within the latter we have event based and task based API's) is simply client-side syntactic sugar:

[image: Visual Studio Proxy Generation]

If you want to see exactly what is generated on the client select the "show all files" button in Visual Studio, and within the Service Reference take a look at Reference.cs:

[image]